# Test URI of web services using scalatest

Tags: java, web-services, scala, scalatest

For example I want to implement rest service which responses to all get requests with pattern

> http://example.com:777/foo/account/010101/2014-11-92

and all urls

> http://exmaple.com:777/foo/account/010101/2014-11-92/somethingelse/andother

I wrote

```
@Path("/foo")
class FooServiceSpec(//injecting other stuff) extends Logging{
@Get
@Path("/account/{id}/{date}/*") 
def foo(@Context uriInfo: UriInfo,
        @PathParam("id") id: String,
        @PathParam("date") date: LocalDateParam): Response = {
//do something
}
}
```

Now I want write FooServiceSpec(using scalatest) for this class to ensure that endpoint provided with this implementation satifies requirements, how I should test urls for this rest service?

Did I write url pattern right?

Answer (score 1):

OK,
This is kind of an old question, but I'd like to offer an answer, for the community.

I'm not, yet, a seasoned [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.orgm) user myself, but I suggest you start [here](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_selenium) if you haven't already:

> http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_selenium

This short guide should introduce you to using the various web-testing browser components the [Selenium project](http://www.seleniumhq.org) has to offer.

Usually, Selenium 3 requires you to have an installation of the web browser you hope to do real-world testing against (Selenium will 'remote-control' the browser). That is true with the exception of the [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net) driver, which is a Java-implementation of a [headless] HTML browser, including JavaScript execution (that means no external browser is necessary with this driver).

**Update**: I came across the following integration of [REST-Assured testing framework](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured) (which I have used, with Java) and ScalaTest.

> [ClientRestSpec.scala](https://github.com/vydra/rest-test/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/testdriven/stormpath/rest/ClientRestSpec.scala)